# Question about Megillas Sefer

Tags: translation, rav-yaakov-emden

In the English translation of “Megilas Sefer,” on page 169 line 4, there is a fragment of a sentence in which the first part of the sentence is missing. This fragment has nothing to do with the preceding lines and introduces an entirely new subject. This seems to be a mistake. In the Kahana edition online, the Hebrew is completely different from the translation at this very point. Is this a mistake on the part of the translator, or is it in fact this way in the Bick edition or manuscript that the translator was using? Thanks.

Comment: Which Sefer is this? Whose translation is this?

Comment: @DonielF it's Rav Yaakov Emben's autobiography. I'm not sure which English translation he's using

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: @robev In that case I’m not sure this is on topic then. Jews not Judaism.

Comment: It’s likely a mistake, possibly even intentional. The English translation is not faithful to either Hebrew ed. and certainly not to the original manuscript. Even the more superior Kahane edition is incomplete so it’s safe to assume any ellipses in the English trans. are plain errors, either in translation or simply incomplete transcription (read: did not restore the omitted/censored original Hebrew text). A while ago Prof. JJ Schacter was working on a critical edition but, alas, AFAIK it has not been published. Rumor has it he was “advised” not to complete his project and publish it.

Comment: In case [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=bLqZCwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA12&ots=CMzIpSDt61&dq=megilat%20sefer%20english&pg=PA169#v=onepage&q&f=false) is the page and line you’re referring to here’s a direct link.

Comment: I'd vtc as unclear. I'm not sure what work you're referring to, let alone what edition you are referencing.

Comment: https://seforimblog.com/2012/03/megillat-sefer-translation-review-by/

Comment: @Alex That comment section really escalated!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the translator skipped from p. 87 line 8 of Kahana ('שקילא טיבותך כו) until p. 91 line 5 (כי הוא ראה אותם). Might have been accidentally, might have been on purpose (as @Oliver said), since some of the material in between (on pages 88-89) are accusations against R' Yonasan Eibeschutz.